# curl certificate Error_ssl.c334: No root certificate specified for verification of other side certificate

Tags: ssl, curl

"""You also need CA certificates bundle file for SSL support. Download cacert.pem from the cURL site, rename it to curl-ca-bundle.crt, and place in the directory where you make installer, or in any directory listed in PATH environment variable."""

I did the same and stored it in `"c:\python27"` 
but it gives me the following error.

value `"C:\Python27\caret.pem" is not valid for "ssl.ca_certs"`
No valid trusted SSL CA  file set . See 'bzr help ssl.ca_certs" for more information on setting trusted certificates.

Answer (score 0):

I got past this error by skipping the rename step.

I downloaded cacert.pem to "C:\Python27\" (no name change) and these errors went away.